# I want to attach multiple files in outlook calendar invite using java

Tags: java, email, calendar, attachment

I want to attach multiple files inside a calendar invite using java. 
Currently i am able to create an invite with the html body text but i am not able to add attachments to that invite.

Does anyone knows how to attach files.

I am not sending the invite as attachment. It is going as normal accept/decline way.

Please post ASAP . 
Thanks in advance

CODE AS FOLLOWS :

```
    MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypes = (MimetypesFileTypeMap) MimetypesFileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap();
    mimetypes.addMimeTypes("text/calendar ics ICS");

    MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) MailcapCommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mailcap.addMailcap("text/calendar;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "  ");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailServer);
    //props.setProperty("mail.user", "emailuser");
    //props.setProperty("mail.password", "");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);


    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    //message.addHeaderLine("text/calendar;method=REQUEST;charset=UTF-8");

  /*  String emailAddress = invite_email;
    String fullName = invite_name;*/

    String emailAddress = "XYZ@aBC.com";
    String fullName = "ABCD";
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(replyEmail, replyEmailName));
    javax.mail.Address address = new InternetAddress(emailAddress, fullName);

    message.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, address);
    message.setSubject("abc" + invite_sub);

    // Create a Multipart
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    //part 1, html text
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = buildHtmlTextPart(team_id);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


    // Add part two, the calendar
    BodyPart calendarPart = buildCalendarPartNew(emailAddress , fullName , invite_sub , invite_uuid ,start_date , finish_date , invite_seq , invite_status , invite_timezone );
    multipart.addBodyPart(calendarPart);

    // Add attachments to the body


    multipart =  addAttachment(multipart,Req_List);


    //update the requisition id list back to " " once the attachment process is over
    Req_List = " ";

    // Put parts in message
    System.out.println("setting the content of message");
    message.setContent(multipart);



    // send message
    try {
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        throw ex;
    }
```

THE FUNCTION FOR ATTACHMENT MAINLY CONTAINS :

```
FileDataSource fds1 = new FileDataSource(sharepath_name);
        attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds1));
attachment.setFileName(fds1.getName());
        attachment.setHeader("MIME-Version", "1.0");
        attachment.setHeader("Content-Type", " "+mime_type+ "; name=\"" + sharepath_name + "\"");
        attachment.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;          filename=\"" + sharepath_name + "\"");
        attachment.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
return multipart;
```

there is no error as such , the invite is getting generated with the text , but the main problem is i want attachments inside the invite, i am not able to attach files inside the invite, i don't know how to attach files inside invite ?
Also the attachments i need to provide multiple attachments inside the invite.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will help if you post some code and also explain why you are 'not able' to add attachments - error message, code not working etc.

Comment: @Stuart i have attached the code and the main problem, the code is executing fine , i am getting the invite but the problem is i am not getting the file attachments. No attachments on the invite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried without setting the attachment headers manually? They should be set by MimeMessage.

Comment: yes i tried without setting the headers and only setting file name and data handler  , but still the same scenario, the invite is getting generated but without any attachment.

Comment: any clue how to resolve this  ?? i need this to work urgently.. Any help regarding this will be appreciated..

Comment: @Vishal I'd suggest taking a message which is known to work, and recreating it from your code.

Comment: thanks i created a fresh calendar invite and tried to attach a document , it worked but the problem now is , when it attaches the document it does not attach the html text part. When i hide the attachment code it takes the html part in the invite. So the html text and attachment are not coming together in the mail..

Comment: @staurt i  have found the issue and it worked now, the problem was i am attaching the files outside the buildHtmlTextPart.. But the attachments should be inside this function , also we need to set the content of the bodypart with a multipart that contains all the bodyparts. so finally i can see the attachments and html content together in the mail.. thanks for your reply stuart. :-)